# Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease'.Host name must not be empty

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, obfuscation, crashlytics

When trying to create a release signed apk, Build fails at task
`app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease'.Host name must not be empty.`

**I have enabled obfuscation** .

```
buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled true // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization

            shrinkResources true // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the Android Gradle plugin


            firebaseCrashlytics {

                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
            }

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Also,using

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    
       apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    
       // Apply the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
    
       apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.0'
    
        //the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
    
        //the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.0'
```

and,

```
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'  // Google Services plugin

        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
```

Anyone facing the same issue?
I tried clearing gradle cache and removing crashlytics dependencies as i read that it will be automatically handled by Android Studio,but crashes are not recorded then.

**Iam using Android Studio 4.1.1(upgraded from previous version)**

> Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, built on November 5, 2020 Runtime
> version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit
> Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Linux 5.4.0-58-generic GC: ParNew,
> ConcurrentMarkSweep Memory: 1246M Cores: 4 Registry:
> ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true,
> external.system.auto.import.disabled=true Non-Bundled Plugins:
> com.android.tool.sizereduction.plugin Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME.

Answer (score 6):

There are Two possible fixes here...

First one which is a **less likely** solution is to rearrange the order of plugins in your build.gradle project file and bring  `apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'` right under the google-services top plugin call in your project's build.gradle file so that you have this arrangement on top BEFORE you call other libraries or apply other plugins needed
So like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

[image]

***- The second solution which is likely and started as at android studio 4.0 up is to edit your global gradle.propeties file installation on your computer...***

Here is the **clearer fix** with pictures below...  (Cos Some may think the *"**gradle.properties**"* file being talked about here is what is in the AS project instead of the global one.

Delete the following lines from the ***"gradle.propeties"*** file on your PC gradle installation location

> systemProp.http.proxyHost= systemProp.https.proxyHost=
> systemProp.https.proxyPort=80 systemProp.http.proxyPort=80

as seen in n my picture below here is a **typical file location** of this ***gradle.propeties*** file
[image]

[image]

***Now click rebuild in your project and VIOLA...  Problem solved***

Comment: works fine, solves the issue. Verified in 2023

Comment: Also, another solution is to delete the following lines from global gradle.properties file.
"systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80"

These can be found on mac in /Users/username/.gradle/gradle.properties
It's a hidden folder. And when you delete this http proxy settings, the internet connection from gradle works properly. Thus no host name error

Answer (score 0):

**To enable Crashlytics mapping file upload for specific product flavors:**

```
import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsExtension

android {
 buildTypes {
   getByName("debug") {
   minifyEnabled = true

   configure<CrashlyticsExtension> {
    mappingFileUploadEnabled = false
   }

 }
}
```